# List not updating in sequential loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I apologize if this is a very simple question. I am still learning Python and could not find an answer to this specific question.

Explanation of what I am trying to do. I am making a population of randomly assorted values. "tour" contains the values are being randomly moved around to create each member of the population. Each member is just a random assortment of these same values. It's essentially a list of lists.

The problem I am having is that the tmp list is not resetting after the first loop. Once the outer for loop finishes its first loop, tmp remains empty despite being made equal to "tour" at the start of each loop.

Here is the snippet of the two loops.

```
    population = []
for x in range(0, 100, 1):
    tmp = tour
    tmptour = []
    while len(tmp) >= 1:
        r = random.randint(0, len(tmp)-1)
        tmptour.append(tmp.pop(r))
    population.append(tmptour)  
return population
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
tmp = tour
```

you're not creating a copy of `tour`, you're just copying the reference. So later when you do

```
tmptour.append(tmp.pop(r))
```

you are actually removing things from `tour`, which is why on the second iteration it's empty.

The fix for this is easy. Rather than setting `tmp` as a reference to `tour`, set it as a copy of `tour`.

```
tmp = tour[:]
```